# I have an error message "The system cannot find the path specified" when installing Caret package in R

Tags: r, r-caret

When I installed CARET package in R, I got following error message.

```
Error in install.packages : path[1]="D:\Users\hrdchs\Documents\.Rhistory\R-3.6.0\library": The system cannot find the path specified
```

I tried to find Document.Rhistory, I could not find the folder ".Rhistory" under Documents folder, I could not find any.  When I tried to manually create folder with name of ".Rhistory", system does not allow a folder name starting with ".".  I guess this may cause the problem. 
Can you please help?

Thanks

In addition to doing `install.packages("caret")`, I tried following: 
It really took a long time but still encountered the same problem.

```
install.packages("caret",
             repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", 
             dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))

setwd("D:/Users/hrdchs/Documents/0 SHR/R/Attrition Analysis/IBM attrition data set")

HRdata <- read.csv("IBMhrData.csv")


library(caret)
```

Comment: you should not look for the folder ".Rhistory", you should look for Documents.Rhistory folder inside  the hrdchs folder.  you cannot create a folder with name starting "."

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I upgraded R from 3.5.1 to version 3.6.0 trying to help to resolve this issue. 
I wonder if this issue is caused by this upgrade.